# Every row get same value in 2d array after assigning different values in java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

'''

```
FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream("test.txt").getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,50000);
    byte[] data = new byte[102];
    byte[][] bufferArray = new byte[(buffer.capacity() / 102)][100];
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        int remaining = data.length;
        if (buffer.remaining() < remaining)
            remaining = buffer.remaining();
        buffer.get(data, 0, remaining);

        bufferArray[i++] = data;
        System.out.println("Value before " + new String(bufferArray[43777]));
        System.out.println("Value before 0 " + new String(bufferArray[0]));
        System.out.println("Value before 100 " + new String(bufferArray[100]));
    }
    System.out.println("Value after 0 " + new String(bufferArray[0]));
    System.out.println("Value after 100 " + new String(bufferArray[100]));
    System.out.println("Value after 43777 " + new String(bufferArray[43777]));
```

'''
*** Values before are different, but values after are all same***
buffer is MappedByteBuffer reading from a txt file

Comment: I believe, its because of i++ .

Comment: You are assigning data1, which is not part of the loop.

Comment: That was a typo !

Comment: Then make sure you post code that compiles and has context. It is hard to read code that is not there

Comment: i have updated the code, reading a file in buffers and setting every 100 bytes from that buffer to a row in 2d array

Comment: I believe you are copying over the array multiple times. Move the "new byte[102]" line] inside the loop and let me know if this changed the behariovr

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: yes it worked, kudos

Comment: I posted it as an answer. accept it if you want. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Move the data array initialization inside the loop. By leaving it outside the code overwrites the same memory repeatedly

```
FileChannel channel = new FileInputStream("test.txt").getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0,50000);
    byte[] data;
    byte[][] bufferArray = new byte[(buffer.capacity() / 102)][100];
    int i = 0;
    while (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
        data = new byte[102];
        int remaining = data.length;
        if (buffer.remaining() < remaining)
            remaining = buffer.remaining();


        buffer.get(data, 0, remaining);
        bufferArray[i++] = data;
        System.out.println("Value before " + new String(bufferArray[43777]));
        System.out.println("Value before 0 " + new String(bufferArray[0]));
        System.out.println("Value before 100 " + new String(bufferArray[100]));
    }
    System.out.println("Value after 0 " + new String(bufferArray[0]));
    System.out.println("Value after 100 " + new String(bufferArray[100]));
    System.out.println("Value after 43777 " + new String(bufferArray[43777]));
```